# Angular: Set LOCALE_ID from config file

Tags: angular

I wonder if there is a way to set locale of application from config file through `LOCALE_ID`.

In `app.module.ts` there is an `APP_INITIALIZER` which loads config into `ConfigService`. And I tried to put there also a `LOCALE_ID` provider with a reference to `ConfigService`, which the config is already loaded in.

```
const initConfigProvider = {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (confService: ConfigService) =>
    () => confService.loadConfig$().toPromise(),
  deps: [ConfigService],
  multi: true
};
const initLocaleProvider = {
  provide: LOCALE_ID,
  useFactory: (confService: ConfigService) =>
    () => { return confService.config.uiCulture; },
  deps: [ConfigService]
};

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    initConfigProvider
    initLocaleProvider
  ]
})
```

Now, there are these errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: value.replace is not a function
    at CldrIntlService.set localeId [as localeId] (index.js:196:1)
    at new CldrIntlService (index.js:184:1)
    at cldrServiceFactory (index.js:134:1)
ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! IntlService
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:5439:1)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11245:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11071:1)
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'locale.toLowerCase is not a function' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4152:1)
    at DecimalPipe.transform (common.js:4887:1)
```

So, can this example be fixed by any minor change or should I choose completely different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem resolved.

`LOCALE_ID` provider needs a function returning *a value*. `APP_INITIALIZER`, in opposite, needs a function returning *a function*, *an Observable* or *a Promise*.

The correct solution is:

```
const initLocaleProvider = {
  provide: LOCALE_ID,
  useFactory: (confService: ConfigService) => { return confService.config.uiCulture; },
  deps: [ConfigService]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`useFactory` expects synchronous return value. Your function returns promise.

You could take advantage of [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER#usage-notes) to load (asynchronously) & store your config. Then you'd be able to use it synchronously.

Comment: Actually, in our application there is already one APP_INITIALIZER, which we load the config asynchronously, as you write. I tried to add another initializer for LOCALE_ID with ConfigService dependency and it really is loaded already, but another bug pops up. I edited question.

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER looks good, but you still return promise in your `initLocaleProvider`. Once you fetch config in `initConfigProvider` store it in `ConfigService` internal property.  Then `initLocaleProvider` should just get and return that previously fetched config.

Comment: Of course, it was some old piece of code... My current code looks like you describe, but still it does not work.

Comment: Attach debugger or use `console.log` to check what's the value of `confService.config.uiCulture`. Also seems you have cyclic dependency for `IntlService`